# I want to know why engineering strain is not a tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, stress-strain

One of the most classical examples in the mechanics of materials is that [engineering strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(mechanics)) is not tensor. I want to know why the engineering strain doesn't meet the tensor definitation.

```
Cauchystrain = {{εx, γxy/2, γxz/2}, {γxy/2, εy, γyz/2}, {γxz/2, γyz/2, εz}};
Engineeringstrain = {{εx, γxy, γxz}, {γxy, εy, γyz}, {γxz, γyz, εz}};
EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}].Engineeringstrain.(EulerMatrix[{α, β, \
γ}]\[Transpose])
EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}].Cauchystrain.(EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]\
\[Transpose])
```

In the above formula, $\frac{1}{2} γxy = εxy,  \frac{1}{2} γxz = εxz,  \frac{1}{2} γyz = εyz$.

I want to know why engineering strain is not a tensor. It is better to demonstrate the specific difference between engineering strain and Cauchy strain with Mathematica.

Comment: It depends on how the body looked at the reference time a finite time ago. I don't think the regular space one works in contains that information. I think it is informally called "two point tensor". That is all I remember on the subject...

Comment: Well, they condensed it down from the full tensor. That simplification means it really can't be used in all the situations one would use the full set of equations (such as inversion).